# Extract character before space from UK postcode

Tags: oracle, substring, extract, postal-code

In my data Postcode records are as below

```
1.'ABC XYZ'
2.' EFG PQR'
```

Requirements is to get all character before space
So for first record ,I am getting expected  result if I am putting

```
select NVL(substr(postcode,0,instr(postcode,' ')-1), postcode)
```

But for second record I am getting whole postcode value . Because in second record `' '`(space is at very beginning).

I tried multiple query but not getting the results .

I want single expression which handles both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NVL(substr(ltrim(postcode),0,instr(ltrim(postcode),' ')-1), postcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option uses regular expressions:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, postcode) as
  2    (select 1, 'ABC XYZ'  from dual union all
  3     select 2, ' EFG PQR' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select id, postcode,
  6    regexp_substr(postcode, '\w+') result
  7  from test;

        ID POSTCODE RESULT
---------- -------- --------
         1 ABC XYZ  ABC
         2  EFG PQR EFG

SQL>
```